# Converting a minecraft pc map to xbox map that has command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-legacy-console

I want to transfert my PC minecraft world to Xbox. It has command blocks that do various things like teleporting. My questiln is, can I convert, and will the command blocks still work?

Answer (score 2):

No. Command blocks now appear in Xbox one, but they have no function. They will not operate and you cannot interact with them. Mojang will likely add this feature in the future, but for now, you cannot have teleporters except in PC. Sorry :(

Comment: i played on a map that was downloaded and they had things like shops and stuff that needs pc and commands in the map it was called legends factions and it was on xbox and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Java (PC) and Bedrock (Xbox PS4 tablets phones VR etc.) are simply **not** compatible. ***Unless***, your PC world is on the Bedrock version and you're playing the Windows 10 edition, I don't believe you can transfer your world. (*NOTE:* just because you may be playing on a computer with Windows 10, doesn't necessarily mean you're playing the Windows 10/Bedrock edition)